# Using Rsync in conjunction with Find

Tags: find, rsync

I'm am attempting to write a script that will copy files created in the last 24 hours AND be of a specific file-type (*.png).

The command I have tried is:

```
rsync -avz --ignore-existing --include='*.png' --exclude='*' \
 --files-from=<(ssh user@remote1 'find /home/admin/Backup/ -mtime -1 -type f -exec basename {} \;') \
  user@remote1:/home/admin/Backup/ /Repository/
```

This works for *.png files in the Backup directory however the command fails when the files are two or three folders deep i.e. located in `/home/admin/Backup/folder1/folder2/` The error I get is

```
link_stat '/home/admin/Backup/example.png' failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

That is because `basename {}` is chopping off the location when it returns the result to `rsync`.  So I tried removing `basename {}` and I get this:

```
link_stat '/home/admin/Backup/home/admin/Backup/folder1/folder2/example.png' failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

It's like `rsync` is appending the source directory and I don't know how to fix it.  Anybody know how to fix this or perhaps I am just going about pulling this file off the remote server the wrong way?

Comment: Is your version `find` allow use `-printf "%P\n"` instead `-exec basename {} \;` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`man rsync` says about `--files-from`:

```
  The  filenames  that  are read from the FILE are all relative to
  the source dir -- any leading slashes are removed  and  no  ".."
  references  are  allowed  to go higher than the source dir.
```

So try making the paths output by `find` relative:

```
rsync -avz ... --files-from=<(ssh user@remote1 'cd /home/admin/Backup/; find . -mtime -1 -type f -name "*.png")
```

Or `find /home/... ... -printf "%P\n"`, since `%P` in [GNU `find`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/find.1) is:

> File's name with the name of the  command  line  argument under which it was found removed.

I have taken the liberty of adding in `-name "*.png"` since I don't see why `rsync` should do the filtering when `find` is capable of it and is already being used.

Comment: Thanks! This works except when the files are synced it copies the directories as well.  What I mean is that instead of placing the .png files in /Repository/ it places them into /Repository/folder1/folder2/ is there a way to just put them into the same directory?

Comment: @Sam try the `--no-implied-dirs` option.

Comment: hmm thought that would work, same results though. Here is what I am doing:rsync -avz --ignore-existing  --files-from=<(ssh user@remote1 'cd /home/admin/Backup/;' 'find . -name "*.png" -type f -mtime -1 -printf "%P\n";') --no-implied-dirs user@remote1:/home/admin/Backup/ /Repository/